# Filebeat Service will not start on CentOS 7

Tags: elasticsearch, centos, system, centos7, filebeat

Filebeat will not start on my CentOS 7 box. I have Logstash running fine, Kibana can be accessed, and I even installed packetbeat to see if it was something wrong with the beats, but Packetbeat works fine.

Here is what is happening when I try to start filebeat:

[image: System status failure]

Here are the filebeat logs:

[image: Filebeat Logs]

My Filebeat config passes the '-configtest' option, so it can't be that. The only output that I get from the debugging option is this:

```
Exiting: Could not start registrar: Error loading state: Error decoding states: EOF
```

I have also tried these two commands to no avail:

```
systemctl reset-failed filebeat.service
systemctl start filebeat.service
```

Anyone have any other commands to try to try and get this to work?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delete the registry file, this is a known issue appartently. [Forum post with an answer from the ELK guys](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-will-not-start-centos-7/74460/2)

```
rm -r /var/lib/filebeat/registry
systemctl reset-failed filebeat
systemctl start filebeat
```

Comment: Good observation :)